# How do I send an email to a specific Discussion Board category?

Tags: 2013, discussion-board, incoming-email

I have a SP 2013 Community site Discussion Board with incoming email enabled.
How do I specify a category (the Categories are enables by default) for a new discussion created by an incoming email in that board?

Answer (score 0):

Discussion board is simply a List, for creating Discussion category you can try adding Custom column(eg: Category) with list options in dropdown(Eg 'CAT-A', 'CAT-B' etc.)

Comment: My fault - I haven't specified this is a Community site with categories enabled by default. Have updated the question.